# SQL query to JPA Joins

Tags: java, sql, jpa

just started using JPA today, so i'm preety new to it.
How would one say 
`"SELECT login.ID, userID, logInTime, logOutTime, user.ID AS 'uID', surname FROM login, user WHERE login.userID = user.ID"` in JPA?
I need to join two tables via the userID.

I looked through a couple of tutorials on the net, but couldn't quite find the anwser to this.
Thanx!

Comment: Could you please describe your domain model? Otherwise it's difficult to advise you on writing JPQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that login and user are now objects, and also assuming that relation between login and user are that one user have many logins will be somthing like this

```
select 
       L.ID,
       u.userID, 
       L.logInTime, 
       L.logOutTime,
       u.ID 
from 
       User U, 
       IN(u.logins) L /*note that the IN makes the inner join between Login and user*/
```

Renember i'm assuming the mapping between the entities

Answer (score 3):

Wildly speculating I would guess that your domain model includes at least two entities `User` and `Login` with the latter representing something like a session. (cardinality `User`-1:n-`Session`)

**My imaginary entities:**

```
@Entity
class User {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<Login> logins;
    ...
}

@Entity
class Login {
    @ManyToOne
    private User;
    ...
}
```

**To retrieve all `Login`s:**

```
jpql: "from Login"
```

(The associated `User` objects are fetched by default. At the @ManyToOne side the default fetch type is eager fetching.)

**To retrieve all `User`s:**

```
jpql: "select u from User u join fetch u.logins"
```

(The associated `List<Login>` objects are not fetched by default. At the @OneToMany side the default fetch type is lazy fetching.)

Getting started with JPA: [openJPA documentation](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.0.1/apache-openjpa-2.0.1/docs/manual/main.html)
(Take a look at chapter 4 and 5 for entity design and chapter 10 for JPQL. The general JPA parts of the openJPA documentation fit all JPA implementations.)

P.S. It would be easier if you put a bit more detail into your questions.

Answer (score 2):

JPQL queries are written against objects, not tables.  It is impossible to write a query without knowing what the objects are and how the relationship between them is defined.

You need to first create Entity objects that represent a `Login` and a `User`.  You map a relationship between them, then that becomes the join for the query.